# Why are threads being added when I open one of my activities?

Tags: android, multithreading, android-asynctask, android-lifecycle, android-task

I haven't been programming for long and don't have great understanding of threading. I was running my app in Eclipse Debug and noticed that whenever I enter Activity C, two threads (AsyncTasks) show up as shown. If I exit the activity and enter again, two more threads appear. Why is this and is this something that shouldn't be happening? Thanks.

[image]